# Deploying an application as a web application and as a native application on either Google's Android or on Apple iOS

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I have a regular web based application written using JSP, HTML, Javascript. Can I use some of the mobile development platforms to deploy it as a native app on either Apples's iOS iPhone or on Android platform?

The idea is to "develop once and run everywhere" - meaning, be able to deploy the same application on multiple platforms such as Web based application, iOS based app and Android based app.

While this would be great, I am unsure if this can be done. I understand that this may be accomplished if the front end part is written in HTML5, CSS3 and Javascript. However, it would be very cumbersome to write the application front-end only using these technologies without either Java or ASP .Net.

Answer (score 1):

To a point: no.

Precisely, you might be able to get a servlet container running on an Android device, but you almost certainly won't be able to pull it off on an iOS device.

Actually writing a front-end application without using server side technologies isn't that difficult with JavaScript and HTML5. Rewriting an existing application is certainly a complex project though.

The currently popular "develop once, run anywhere" platforms for mobile devices are Apache Callout (previously PhoneGap) and Appcelerator Titanium.

Callout is based on making a thin Webkit shell as a native application, and then injecting interfaces towards the phone's features into the JavaScript context of that Webkit instance. It's easier to get into than Titanium, and it is completely free.

Titanium is also JavaScript based, but partially compiles your JavaScript code into native code which is then compiled by your native development stack for each platform. The upside is somewhat more responsive program. Some features require buying a license.

Having tested both during the last two weeks, I believe that depending on such solutions at this time amounts to technological suicide. Both of these systems are slow, buggy and even require licensing. Users will recognize apps made with them and generally reward you with poor ratings and reviews on markets.